# C++ operator overload doesnt work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a question about operators and how to overload them. There is an example of code and I'm overloading `operator<<` but it doesn't work. There is class that I use:

```
class CStudent{ //class for students and their attributes
    int m_id;
    int m_age;
    float m_studyAverage;

    public:

    CStudent(int initId, int initAge, float initStudyAverage): m_id(initId), m_age(initAge), m_studyAverage(initStudyAverage){}

    int changeId(int newId){
        m_id = newId;
        return m_id;
    }
    int increaseAge(){
        m_age++;
        return m_age;
    }
    float changeStudyAverage(float value){
        m_studyAverage += value;
        return m_studyAverage;
    }
    void printDetails(){
        cout << m_id << endl;
        cout << m_age << endl;
        cout << m_studyAverage << endl;
    }

    friend ostream operator<< (ostream stream, const CStudent student);
};
```

Overload:

```
ostream operator<< (ostream stream, const CStudent student){
    stream << student.m_id << endl;
    stream << student.m_age << endl;
    stream << student.m_studyAverage << endl;
    return stream;
}
```

And there is main method:

```
int main(){

    CStudent peter(1564212,20,1.1);
    CStudent carl(154624,24,2.6);

    cout << "Before the change" << endl;
    peter.printDetails();
    cout << carl;

    peter.increaseAge(); 
    peter.changeStudyAverage(0.3);
    carl.changeId(221783);
    carl.changeStudyAverage(-1.1);

    cout << "After the change" << endl;
    peter.printDetails();
    cout << carl;

    return 0;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What does not work? Is there a compiler error message or a run-time bug?

Comment: operator<< should take a reference to an ostream (std::ostream &) as it's 1st parameter, and it should also take a const reference (CStudent const &) as it's 2nd parameter. Last but not least it should return a reference to the passed-in ostream. So to sum it up: `friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, CStudent const & student)`

Comment: @pmr there is an error i cant compile it

Comment: @ChrisBarlow: So *tell us what error you get*! Don't make it unnecessarily hard to help you by withholding information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you need to learn what references are and the difference between std::ostream and std::ostream& is.

`std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const CStudent& student)`

Comment: Thank you that was it, dont know how i missed it